# Salesforce to salesforce rest api integration

Tags: apexrest

### Trigger:

```
trigger Intglead on Lead (After Insert) {
List<string> lsstr= new List<string>();
for(Lead xt:Trigger.new)
  {  
   lsstr.add(String.valueOf(xt.LastName));
   lsstr.add(String.valueOf(xt.Company));
   lsstr.add(String.valueOf(xt.Status));
  }
  SendLeadUsingRESTAPI.callcreateAcc(lsstr);
}
```

## Apex class:

```
public class SendLeadUsingRESTAPI {
   private final String clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
   private final String clientSecret = 'xxxxxx';
   private final String username = 'xxxxxxxx';
   private final String password = 'xxxxxxxxx';

   public class deserializeResponse
   {
      public String id;
      public String access_token;
   }

   public String ReturnAccessToken (SendLeadUsingRESTAPI leada)
   {
      String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
      Http h = new Http();
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setBody(reqbody);
      req.setMethod('POST');
      req.setEndpoint('https://na30.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
      HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
      deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
      return resp1.access_token;
   }

   @future(callout=true)
   public static void callcreateAcc (List<String> l)
   {
      List<string> js = new List<string>();
      SendLeadUsingRESTAPI leadb = new SendLeadUsingRESTAPI();
      String accessToken;
      accessToken = leadb.ReturnAccessToken(leadb);
      for(string s : l)
      {
          js.add(s);
      }      
      if(accessToken != null){
          String endPoint = 'https://na30.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Lead/doPost';
          String jsonstr = (String)JSON.serialize(js);
          System.debug('hello'+jsonstr);
          Http h2 = new Http();
          HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
          req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
          req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
          req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
          req1.setBody(jsonstr);
          req1.setMethod('POST');
          req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
          HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);
       }
    }
}
```

## Target Org Webservice Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Lead/doPost')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {
@HttpPost
    global static String doPost(String name,
        String Company, String Status) {
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.LastName = name;
        ld.Company = Company;
        ld.Status = Status;
        insert ld;
        return ld.Id;
    }
}
```

I am trying to integrate if lead created in one org it will automatically created in another org using apex rest.

I am getting error:

```
12:44:02.19 (413305091)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[35]|endPoint|"https://na30.salesfo (37 more) ..."
12:44:02.19 (413307102)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[36]
12:44:02.19 (413317598)|METHOD_ENTRY|[36]||System.JSON.serialize(Object)
12:44:02.19 (413643659)|METHOD_EXIT|[36]||System.JSON.serialize(Object)
12:44:02.19 (413650492)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[36]|jsonstr|String|false|false
12:44:02.19 (413662132)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[36]|jsonstr|"[\"youtest7\",\"rt7\",\"N (4 more) ..."
12:44:02.19 (413665227)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[37]
12:44:02.19 (413668691)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[37]|Bytes:5
12:44:02.19 (413685019)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[37]|Bytes:29
12:44:02.19 (413723066)|USER_DEBUG|[37]|DEBUG|hello["youtest7","rt7","New"]
12:44:02.19 (413730586)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[38]
12:44:02.19 (413751628)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[38]|h2|System.Http|true|false
12:44:02.19 (413791469)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[38]|h2|"System.Http[]"|0x76c7719a
12:44:02.19 (413795785)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[39]
12:44:02.19 (413810854)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[39]|req1|System.HttpRequest|true|false
12:44:02.19 (413849167)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[39]|req1|"System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=null, Method=null]"|0x42bcd6d0
12:44:02.19 (413853947)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[40]
12:44:02.19 (413858158)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[40]|Bytes:13
12:44:02.19 (413861861)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[40]|Bytes:7
12:44:02.19 (413868267)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[40]|Bytes:119
12:44:02.19 (413926757)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[41]
12:44:02.19 (413931817)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[41]|Bytes:12
12:44:02.19 (413935344)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[41]|Bytes:16
12:44:02.19 (413965572)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[42]
12:44:02.19 (413969978)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[42]|Bytes:6
12:44:02.19 (413997079)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[43]
12:44:02.19 (414026520)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[44]
12:44:02.19 (414051825)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[45]
12:44:02.19 (414072712)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[46]
12:44:02.19 (416325080)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[46]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://na30.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Lead/doPost, Method=POST]
12:44:02.19 (500457659)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:389
12:44:02.19 (500534441)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[46]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
12:44:02.19 (500557728)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[46]|Bytes:120
12:44:02.19 (500589704)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[46]|res1|System.HttpResponse|true|false
12:44:02.19 (500666784)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[46]|res1|"System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]"|0x68aa2c88
12:44:02.500 (500691680)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
12:44:02.500 (500691680)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
```

Comment: your 400 error is best debugged by using curl  to verify the POST body and header - get that working first

Comment: Might you have the unit test for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending list of strings :

```
["youtest7","rt7","New"]
```

And in service you're expecting lead fields:

```
doPost(String name, String Company, String Status)
```

You have to send lead object with field names:

```
{"name":"youtest7","Company":"rt7","Status":"New"}
```

Or you can deserialize list of leads in SF instance A, and receive them in instance B.

- Pass set of lead ids to future method
- Select your list
- Set ids as Null (you cann't use id in insert)
- Serialize it and send to instance B
- In instance b deserialise it and save

Instance A:

```
list<Lead> leads = [select lastname, company, status from lead limit 2]; //where id in :ids
for (Lead ld :leads)
    ld.id = null;

String jsonstr = (String)JSON.serialize(leads);
system.debug(jsonstr);
```

Json gonna look like:

```
[{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "Lead"
    },
    "LastName": "Boxer",
    "Company": "Farmers Coop. of Florida",
    "Status": "Working - Contacted",
    "Id": null
},..
```

Instance B:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Lead/doPost')
global with sharing class MyLeadResource {
@HttpPost
    global static String doPost() {
        list<Lead> leadToInsert = (list<Lead>)System.JSON.deserialize(
            RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring(), 
            list<Lead>.class);

        system.debug(leadToInsert);

        insert(leadToInsert);

        return leadToInsert[0].id;
    }
}
```

*Of course you can add some error handling, or number of inserted leads..*

Comment: I don't have experience with Salesforce-to-Salesforce interface, may be it can be easier to implement.